# How would I include the output from a project in msbuild deployment from a project built afterward

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, msbuild, nopcommerce

I am working with NopCommerce.  The framework is built in such a way that allows the creation of plugins as additional projects in the solution.  These projects have to reference the "Core" which is essentially the MVC website that gets deployed.

Due to the nature of msbuild, I cannot think of any way (without hacks) to get the output of the plugin projects build (dll files) to be included in the Core build deployment because the plugins are required to build the core first.

I understand this is a circular dependency, and I also understand that in a normal situation, one would not require the plugins to even know the web project exists...  But this is how it is when using NopCommerce.

I have tried to do the following with msbuild in the website csproj file:

```
<Target Name="NopTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildPlugins Include="..\..\Plugins\**\*.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="directory: @(BuildPlugins)" Importance="HIGH" />

    <MSBuild Projects="@(BuildPlugins)" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <NopPlugins Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Plugins\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="@(BuildPlugins)" Importance="HIGH" />
    <Message Text="After Build Plugin Copy - @(NopPlugins) - $(TargetDir)\%(RecursiveDir)" Importance="HIGH" />

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(NopPlugins)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)\Plugins\%(RecursiveDir)" />
```

... but I think its a giant mess.  Also, it only seems to work properly on my dev machine.  When I try it in devops, I get a bunch of nuget package errors related to failed restore.  Again, it's an issue with circular dependencies, or build order.

(FYI, I'm working on a parameterized deployment to use with Azure Devops)

Answer (score 0):

> ... but I think its a giant mess. Also, it only seems to work properly
>   on my dev machine. When I try it in devops, I get a bunch of nuget
>   package errors related to failed restore. Again, it's an issue with
>   circular dependencies, or build order.

Since it works in your local machine, I assume it's just something wrong with your restore step. And it caused next build error.

According to your script, your `core` project and `plugins` project are not in same directory level. So your `nuget/dotnet restore` task should run **twice** to restore packages for both two project separately if the `plugins` project is not defined in `xx.sln` file.

If your project targets `.net framework`, use [nuget restore task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops), or use the restore command in [use .net core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) if your projects target `.net core/standard`. Just make sure you've restored packages for all the projects.